# How can i run the fixture before other fixtures? pytest python3.7

Tags: pytest, python-3.7, fixtures

I want to run the fixture before other fixtures.

How can I set one function to run before all the function in "conftest.py"?

my function:

```
@pytest.mark.run(order=1)
@fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def init_test_failures():
    test_failures.clear()
```

[example for the ordering in allure report - need to this function to be the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIc75.png)

Comment: Not sure I understand: do you want to run the fixture before other fixtures (in this case, just write it first in your test function), or do you want to run it before each test without mentioning it in the argument list?

Comment: Also, you may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660064/in-which-order-are-pytest-fixtures-executed?rq=1).

Comment: I want run the fixture before other fixtures, and i write the function first in the test, but it still not working

Comment: Can you edit your post to show how you use the fixture?

Comment: @fixture(autouse=True) <br/>
def init_test_failures(): <br/>
    test_failures.clear()<br/>
<br/>
i have same fixture function with scope=module or session

Comment: Ok, I understand you have several autouse fixtures and want this one to run first? You could derive the other fixtures from this one in this case.

Comment: you mean calling them from that function?

Comment: Derive them, e.g. `def other_fixture(init_test_failures):`

Comment: Which actually means using them (e.g. calling them), as this is not real derivation, of course.